# Prestashop 1.7 custom product field back office problem with get data, saving ok

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I created custom field `warranty` in admin backoffice in product detail. I can save value by textbox its ok.
But value not load in textbox.

There is some problem with get data. I tried dump ($product->warranty); in ModelAdapter and value is NULL but in database not;

Prestashop version 1.7.6.2

I tried some older solutions but doesn't work.

My Code:

**/override/classes/Product.php**

```
class Product extends ProductCore
{
....
public $warranty;
      
    public function __construct($id_product = null, $full = false, $id_lang = null, $id_shop = null, Context $context = null)
    {
     self::$definition['fields']['warranty'] = array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'lang' => false);
     ...
        parent::__construct($id_product, $full, $id_lang, $id_shop, $context);
    }
```

**src/PrestaShopBundle/Model/Product/AdminModelAdapter.php**

```
private function mapStep6FormData(Product $product)
{
    return array(
        'visibility' => $product->visibility,
        'tags' => $this->getTags($product),
        'display_options' => [
            'available_for_order' => (bool) $product->available_for_order,
            'show_price' => (bool) $product->show_price,
            'online_only' => (bool) $product->online_only,
        ],
        'upc' => $product->upc,
        'ean13' => $product->ean13,
        'warranty' => $product->warranty,
```

**src/PrestaShopBundle/Form/Admin/Product/ProductOption.php**

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
  ...
        ->add('warranty', FormType\TextType::class, [
            'required' => false,
            'error_bubbling' => true,
            'label' => 'Warranty',
            'empty_data' => '',
        ])
```

**src/PrestaShopBundle/Resources/views/Admin/Product/ProductPage/Panels/options.html.twig**

```
      <fieldset class="col-md-4 form-group">
        <label class="form-control-label">
          {{ optionsForm.warranty.vars.label }}
          <span class="help-box" data-toggle="popover"
                data-content="Záruka počet měsíců"></span>
        </label>
        {{ form_errors(optionsForm.warranty) }}
        {{ form_widget(optionsForm.warranty) }}
      </fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you solved it yet, but it worked for me to avoid the change you made in src/PrestaShopBundle/Model/Product/AdminModelAdapter.php

**EDIT:**
I had to add the next line to src/PrestaShopBundle/Model/Product/AdminModelAdapter.php::mapStep2FormData()

```
'pvl_price' => $product->pvl_price,
```

in the return statement for having all working propperly.
In your case i guess the line should be:

```
'warranty' => $product->warranty,
```